# Using simple matrix algebra to solve for a specific matrix (Beginner question)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multiplicative-order

The matrix $AB = C$ where $A$, $B$ and $C$ are all $2 \times 2$ non-singular matrices.

How would I go about to solve for the Matrix $A$ and express it in terms of $B$ and $C$?

There are two methods I found but they give different answers.

Method 1:

Multiply both sides on the left by $B^{-1}$ so $B^{-1}(AB)=B^{-1}C$

Then rewrite as $B^{-1}BA=B^{-1}C$ since multiplication is associative

$IA=B^{-1}C$ therefore $A=B^{-1}C$

However the answer is different if instead I multiply on the right by $B^{-1}$ which is what I would have done instead (and is the correct answer).

Method 2:

$(AB)B^{-1}=CB^{-1}$

$AI=CB^{-1}$

$A=CB^{-1} $

My question is, why is it that method 1 is incorrect? What is the mistake and could someone elaborate on the general rules I should follow to solve questions like this.

Comment: Matrix multiplication is associative yes, but it is not commutative. What you have stated $AB = BA$ is the property of commutativity of matrix multiplication, which does not hold in general.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplication of matrices is associative, but NOT commutative, so $B^{-1}AB$ is not the same as $B^{-1}BA$.

Here's a counterexample to commutativity:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 3 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \neq \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: But suppose you had matrices such as ABC, then you can evaluate them as A(BC) or A(CB) right? So in the same way, is it not possible to do what I did above and switch the order?

Comment: No, you got it wrong. You can evaluate $ABC$ as $A(BC)$ or $(AB)C$.

Comment: Oh I understand now. So the matrices must remain in order but I can evaluate the products in between. Thank you.